# Phalcon Tag working at /index/index.phtml but not at /signup/index.phtml

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm following the tutorial at Phalcon's page (https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/tutorial-base) and I got stuck at creating the /view/signup/index.phtml.

When I access the /signup/index.phtml page it only shows me the HTML tags, that is, "Sign up using this form". None of the `$this->tag` show. I copied the linkTo tag from the /views/index/index.phtml to the signup view but it didn't work as well, even though it's working perfectly in the index/index.phtml. Somehow no Tag is working at the /signup view.

Does anyone know why?

### The codes

**/app/controllers/SignupController.php**

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
       {

       }
}
```

**/app/views/signup/index.phtml**

```
<h2>Sign up using this form</h2>

<?php echo $this->tag->form("signup/register"); ?>

<p>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <?php echo $this->tag->textField("name"); ?>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <?php echo $this->tag->textField("email"); ?>
</p>

<p>
    <?php echo $this->tag->submitButton("Register"); ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are not supposed to be accessed directly. Try to use [Phalcon Developer Tools](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/devtools-usage) to set up your app skeleton or use the [**simple** MVC example](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/simple). Notice that you must have `mod_rewrite` enabled (if you are working in Apache). Then continue following the tutorial (create the `Loader`, `DI` with `view`, etc) and you will be surprised by the magic of Phalcon. Good luck!

Comment: I used the Phalcon Developer Tools and set up a new project and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Check your URL**

Are you using `/signup/index.phtml` in your browsers address bar?

You should have something like `localhost/tutorial/signup`

You will be able to visually see templates by going to their path directly, but the php will not run.

**Not all resources being included**

If you are using the URL paths seen in the tutorial, check that all resources are being loaded into the SignupController correctly by doing the following:

`var_dump($this->tag)`

This should display something in regards to "form" or a whole bunch of text. If you see nothing the `Phalcon\Tag' class is not loading in correctly.

You probably may even have a typo somewhere. I would recommend copying and pasting the tutorial instead of typing, only while bug checking, to make sure there are no typos. You can use a tool like a diff checker to compare your files to their tutorial.

Online diff checker : https://www.diffchecker.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I copied all the text and somehow it didn't work. So I used the Phalcon Devtools to create it and it worked.

Comment: Np. I guess I should not have assumed your environment would be the same as theirs